# AVPlayerViewController background color clear

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I tried setting background color of AVPlayerViewController to clear color but it has no effect. It sets it back to black. Every other color works, except clear color. Is there anyway or workaround to set it as clear color?

```
   playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
   playerController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: Did you try UIColor.white.withAlpha 0

Comment: Doesn't work either :(

Comment: If your video is not exported with an alpha channel then you will always have a black background. You also need to set  `playerLayer?.pixelBufferAttributes = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]` for alpha transparency to work.